# Eslint: How to disable "unexpected console statement" in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, eslint

I'm using eslint with Sublime Text 3 and I am writing `gulpfile.js`.

```
/*eslint-env node*/
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    console.log('default task');
});
```

But eslint keeps showing error : "Error: Unexpected console statement. (no-console)"
[image: eslint error]

I found [official document here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console.html), but I still don't know how to disable it.

```
/*eslint-env node*/
var gulp = require('gulp');

/*eslint no-console: 2*/
gulp.task('default', function(){
    console.log('default task');
});
```

doesn't work, either.

My Sublime Text 3 plugins: SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint.

Here's my `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    "rules": {
        "no-console":0,
        "indent": [
            2,
            "tab"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            2,
            "single"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            2,
            "unix"
        ],
        "semi": [
            2,
            "always"
        ]
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended"
};
```

Answer (score 594, accepted):

Create a .eslintrc.js in the directory of your file, and put the following contents in it:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'no-console': 'off',
    },
};
```

Comment: Well, according to the official github page for the eslint plugin (https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint#i-want-to-use-global-eslintrc-config), putting a .eslintrc file into your project folder should do the trick...to continue debugging it, I'd recommend trying to run eslint from the command line. Simply install node.js if you don't have it installed, then run `npm install eslint` from a console/command prompt, then navigate to your project folder in a console/command prompt, and run `eslint .`

Comment: It remains the same problem.  http://i.imgur.com/nIvrUih.png This is also useless.

Comment: hmm, this is very strange...could you create the `.eslintrc` file that I mentioned in the answer in the same folder as your file, then run: `eslint gulpfile.js -c .eslintrc` and see if it works then?

Comment: My file is `.eslintrc.js` not `.eslintrc`, is it correct?

Comment: @JeanYang yeah, that's an issue. Name it just `.eslintrc`, and then it should work in sublime just fine.

Comment: If i rename it to `.eslintrc`, the console throws an error.  The console mistook it as a YAML file.  http://i.imgur.com/ffavJJT.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97575/discussion-between-markasoftware-and-jean-yang).

Comment: it works (for me)  when the file is called .eslintrc.json

Comment: Alternatively, you can write `"rules": {"no-console": "off"}` to be less cryptic.  `"warn"` and `"error"` being the other 2 options.

Comment: The ESLint configuration file used to be simply `.eslintrc` but now that is deprecated and should be named according to the format used, e.g. `.eslintrc.js`, `.eslintrc.yaml`, etc.

Comment: @ColinDBennett i said .js in my answer, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: this syntax won't work for a `.js` file, thats `.json`

Comment: it will now @PetrosKyriakou!

Comment: A .js config is easier to use than a .json config for me. I can have trailing commas in a .js file, but .json config won't allow it.

Comment: Does not work in **vue-cli 3**: see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53333105/150370

Answer (score 218):

You should update eslint config file to fix this permanently. Else you can temporarily enable or disable eslint check for console like below

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
console.log(someThing);
/* eslint-enable no-console */
```

Comment: How to config my `.eslintrc`, please tell me?

Comment: Not is necessary to add both lines. With only put previous of your `console.log` the following exception is enough: `eslint-disable-next-line no-console`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanBrizio that's exactly what I wanted. A quick and dirty solution to debug something. When I'm done, I will remove the console.log line. I don't want to permanently modify the eslint rules.

Answer (score 151):

For **vue-cli 3** open `package.json` and under section `eslintConfig` put `no-console` under `rules` and restart dev server (`npm run serve` or `yarn serve`)

```
...
"eslintConfig": {
    ...
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, as @markasoftware solution does not work if you come here for a cue-cli project.

Comment: package.json isn't the only way to do this.  Separate config files are also a standar.

Comment: Thanks! Rules in docs: configuration https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules, rules: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Comment: Which package.json file?

Comment: the one in the root folder @MaxRocket

Answer (score 61):

The following works with ESLint in VSCode if you want to disable the rule for just one line.

To disable the next line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log('hello world');
```

To disable the current line:

```
console.log('hello world'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
```

Answer (score 42):

A nicer option is to make the display of console.log and debugger statements conditional based on the node environment.

```
  rules: {
    // allow console and debugger in development
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0,
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0,
  },
```

Comment: console msgs still print in production environment

Comment: how would this work if .eslintrc is in JSON not regular js file?

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively instead of turning 'no-console' off, you can allow. In the **.eslintrc.js** file put

```
  rules: {
    "no-console": [
     "warn",
     { "allow": ["clear", "info", "error", "dir", "trace", "log"] }
    ]
  }
```

This will allow you to do `console.log` and `console.clear` etc without throwing errors.

Comment: Needs to be JSON, not a JavaScript Object

Comment: `.eslintrc.js` is a JS file, so it does not need to be JSON.

Answer (score 16):

If you install eslint under your local project, you should have a directory /node_modules/eslint/conf/ and under that directory a file eslint.json. You could edit the file and modify "no-console" entry with the value "off" (although 0 value is supported too):

```
"rules": {
    "no-alert": "off",
    "no-array-constructor": "off",
    "no-bitwise": "off",
    "no-caller": "off",
    "no-case-declarations": "error",
    "no-catch-shadow": "off",
    "no-class-assign": "error",
    "no-cond-assign": "error",
    "no-confusing-arrow": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    ....
```

I hope this "configuration" could help you.

Comment: Even better, just run this handy script on all your files: `find . -name '*.js' -exec gawk -i inplace 'NR==1{print "/* eslint-disable */"} {print}' {} \;`

Comment: Rules in docs: configuration https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules, rules: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to disable the rule once, you want to look at [Exception's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215841/192961).

You can improve this by only disabling the rule for one line only:

... on the current line:

```
console.log(someThing); /* eslint-disable-line no-console */
```

... or on the next line:

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-console */
console.log(someThing);
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Ember.js which generates a file named `.eslintrc.js`. Adding `"no-console": 0` to the rules object did the job for me. The updated file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  extends: 'eslint:recommended',
  env: {
    browser: true
  },
  rules: {
    "no-console": 0
  }
};
```

Answer (score 10):

in my `vue` project i fixed this problem like this :

```
vim package.json
...
"rules": {
    "no-console": "off"
},
...
```

`ps :  package.json is a configfile in the vue project dir, finally the content shown like this：`

```
{
  "name": "metadata-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: this is helpful if one generated a vue project trough `vue-cli` or `vue ui` and it contains a `vue.config.js` and `package.json`. Edit the `package.json`.

Answer (score 9):

2018 October,

just do:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
```

the anothers answer with

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
```

does not work !

Answer (score 9):

If you're still having trouble even after configuring your package.json according to the documentation (if you've opted to use package.json to track rather than separate config files):

```
"rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
```

And it still isn't working for you, **don't forget you need to go back to the command line and do npm install again**. :)

Comment: Interesting, that what happened to me. Why did we need to run **npm install** again? Or perhaps I just needed to restart with **npm run serve**.

Answer (score 5):

In **package.json** you will find an `eslintConfig` line. Your 'rules' line can go in there like this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
   ...
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
   ...
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

You should add one rule and add your env:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off"
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  }
}
```

you can add other envs.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can restrict only some methods on the console object with:

```
"rules": {
    ...
    "no-console": [
      "error",
      {
        "allow": [
          "log",
          "error"
        ]
      }
    ],
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

in "rules",
"no-console": [false, "log", "error"]

Answer (score 1):

### To just allow `console.error()`

warn the `consoles` for the debug proposes.

> Add other console types in the array if needed.

```js
module.exports = {
// ...
  rules: {
     // ...
    "no-console": ["warn", { "allow": ["error"] }],
  },
// ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents contribution:

**Besides** removing the console warning (as shown above), it's best to remove yours logs from PROD environments (for security reasons).
The best way I found to do so, is by adding this to *nuxt.config.js*

```
  build: {
   terser: {
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          //this removes console.log from production environment
          drop_console: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How it works: Nuxt already uses terser as minifier. This config will force terser to ignore/remove all console logs commands during compression.

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround to avoid using the **eslint-disable-next-line no-console**, or adding rule in .eslintrc, or getting an Eslint warning. You can create a tempotary variable and call it instead.

```
const cons = console;
cons.log('My message here'); // <- won't see warning here
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure that the name of the folder that the flutter project is in. Doesn't have spaces. that was my error

Answer (score -6):

Use Window Object

`window.console.log("..")`

Comment: This answers the question succinctly and should not be downvoted. In my case, I either have to edit an `.env` file then rebuild or use a comment `// eslint-disable-next-line no-console`. Both of which are more tedious than this approach.

I can simply use this for quick testing then remove when I'm done. Thank you!