# error You should use the "log" method of the AngularJS Service $log instead of the console object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am trying on a dummy project and facing this error while using `console.log('debug anything');` in javascript files. I am using gulp and new to the technology so I couldn't figure out whats happening.

My project is running fine but terminal shows all console.debug() statements as errors.

I tried searching for it and found that `.eslintrc` file should be modified but that didn't worked. I followed the below link

[Eslint: How to disable “unexpected console statement” in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215526/eslint-how-to-disable-unexpected-console-statement-in-node-js)

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: hmm, have you installed eslint on your node js env?

Comment: yes..Yeoman generator for AngularJS + Gulp. must have installed it. 
I tried installing it separately also but the errors didn't go.

Comment: have you installed `generator-eslint` as its mentioend here ? https://github.com/eslint/generator-eslint

Comment: I just now tried installing generator-eslint but the errors persisted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a file name *.eslintrc* parallel to `node_modules` folder and write below content and save and check

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "plugins": ["angular"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jasmine": true
  },
  "rules":{
      "no-console": 0,
      "angular/log": 0
  }
}
```