# How to enable console logging in production mode for vue.js

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg

when I use the "yarn build" command to build vue.js project, I get "Unexpected console statement" error.

For development I am using my own server. yarn run starts its own server. So I have to build the project using yarn and deploy the build to my server. But I cannot have console.log() statements.

Comment: This error comes from your linter. Check the documentation for your linter for how to resolve it.

Comment: Have you tried [Eslint: How to disable “unexpected console statement” in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53333105/3499595)? The linked answer is even about Vue CLI 3 projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can seed the logs with the shared commands.
./node_modules/.bin/pm2 logs