# How to create a global custom console.log handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, eslint

I have an eslint rule that will throw an error if there’s a console.log.

I’d like to create a handler called “Console.log” that does the same thing but won’t be picked up by the eslint rule.

Is there a way to make this globally available in a react project without having to import it anywhere?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change the rule?

Comment: I believe this is the most appropriate way to solve it as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215651/16732460

Comment: @iunfixit this will just allow console logs throughout the project. I only want to allow a couple console logs

Comment: You can manually allow some console logs with `// eslint-disable-next-line no-console`, a custom handler would create the same problem as with the normal log